# TAR over two hops

Tags: ssh, tar, scp, remote-server

I need to create a tar and shipped it to my local folder.
If i can create tar file, i can easily get it on local folder using scp.
Here problem is at first step: Creating TAR on remote server. Server is accessible only through another remote server (bastion server).

Here is the command i'm using currently:

```
timestamp="20160226-085856"
ssh bastion_server -t ssh remote_server "sudo su -c \"cp -r /etc/nginx /home/ubuntu/backup/nginx_26Feb && cd /home/ubuntu/backup && tar -C /home/ubuntu/backup -cf backup_nginx-$timestamp.tar ./nginx_26Feb\" "
```

Here is the error i am getting:

```
su: invalid option -- 'r'
Usage: su [options] [LOGIN]
```

Any help here would be great.

Comment: Some more errors :
```
tar: ./nginx_20160310-231329: Cannot stat: No such file or directory tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try without the fancy `sudo su -c`. Using `sudo -s` should be enough:

```
ssh bastion_server -t ssh remote_server "sudo -s cp -r /etc/nginx \
  /home/ubuntu/backup/nginx_26Feb && cd /home/ubuntu/backup && \
  tar -C /home/ubuntu/backup -cf backup_nginx-$timestamp.tar ./nginx_26Feb"
```

Or rather set up proper two-hops `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host bastion
  Hostname bastion_server
Host remote
  Hostname remote_server
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p bastion
```

and then just run

```
ssh remote sudo su -c "cp -r /etc/nginx /home/ubuntu/backup/nginx_26Feb \
 && cd /home/ubuntu/backup && tar -C /home/ubuntu/backup -cf \
 backup_nginx-$timestamp.tar ./nginx_26Feb"
```

Without the fancy escaping and stuff.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work for me. Again the same error : 
--------
      tar: ./nginx_20160310-231329: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
      tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: It is different error than in the question. So either the code you run is different or you have some different version of `tar` on server. Please update your question with the information what you have run and what exact error you got. In the comments it is not visible clearly.